# Time evolution operator in the Heisenberg picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, definition, time-evolution

For an operator $A$, we can show that $\langle A_H \rangle = \langle A_{S} \rangle$, since
$$\langle \Psi_S(t)| A_S|\Psi_S(t)\rangle = \langle \Psi_S(0)| U^{\dagger}A_S U|\Psi_S(0)\rangle$$
$$U^{\dagger}A_S U = A_H.$$
Thus
$$\langle A_S\rangle = \langle A_H\rangle.$$
However, where exactly does $U^{\dagger}A_S U = A_H$ come from?

Whenever I try to find how exactly we get the relation above I keep getting the proof above, which doesn't explain the relation. What Am I missing?

Comment: "Whenever I try to find how exactly we get the relation above I keep getting the proof above, which doesn't explain the relation. What Am I missing?" You seem to be missing that it is a *definition*. The *definition* of a Heisenberg picture operator $X_H(t)$ is $X_H(t) = U^\dagger(t) X_S U(t)$ for any operator $X$.

Answer (score 3):

This relation is the definition of an operator in the Heisenberg picture (if we take the Schrodinger picture as our starting point). In the Schrodinger picture, the state of one system is described as a time-evolving vector in the Hilbert space, $|\psi_S(t) \rangle = U(t) | \psi_0 \rangle$, and observables as fixed Hermitian operators such as $A_S$. With this formalism, we can compute physical quantities such as expectation values of observables

\begin{equation}
\langle \psi_S(t) | A_S | \psi_S(t) \rangle = \langle \psi_0| U^{\dagger}(t) A_S U(t) | \psi_0 \rangle
\end{equation}

In the Heisenberg picture, we describe the state of the system by a fixed vector, $|\psi_H \rangle = |\psi_0 \rangle$, and observables as time-evolving operators $A_H(t)$. But physical quantities, such as expectation values, must have the same value in both pictures. This is a physicality condition that we **demand** from our definitions. So we must define the Heisenberg picture operator in such a way that

\begin{equation}
\langle \psi_H | A_H(t) | \psi_H \rangle = \langle \psi_0| U^{\dagger}(t) A_S U(t) | \psi_0 \rangle = \langle \psi_H| U^{\dagger}(t) A_S U(t) | \psi_H \rangle
\end{equation}

Since this must be true for any state $|\psi_H \rangle$, we find that the right definition is $A_H = U^{\dagger}(t) A_S U(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

Given an operator $A$, suppose $A_S$ is the operator in the *Schrödinger Picture* which doesn't evolve in time, then we have,
$$ \langle \Psi_S(t)| A_S|\Psi_S(t)\rangle = \langle \Psi_S(0)| U^{\dagger}(t) A_S U(t)|\Psi_S(0)\rangle, $$
where $U(t)$ is the time evolution operator. Now, let us say we want operators $A_H$ that evolve with time, i.e, $A_H \equiv A_H(t)$ and states $|\Psi_H\rangle$ that are fixed and do not evolve with time. One can identify that, $U^{\dagger}(t) A_S U(t)$ depends on time and $|\Psi_S(0)\rangle$ does not evolve in time. Thus we **define** the states and operators in the *Heisenberg Picture* as,
$$ |\Psi_H\rangle := |\Psi_S(0)\rangle \quad ; \quad A_H := U^{\dagger}(t) A_S U(t), \\ \implies \langle \Psi_S(t)| A_S|\Psi_S(t)\rangle = \langle \Psi_H| A_H(t)|\Psi_H\rangle$$
As one would expect, the different pictures give the same expectation values while on the whole revealing two completely different ways of going about our computations!